# Appending javascript value to gridview hyperlink. Any ideas why my code doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

We have a javascript that takes start date and end date, calculates the difference between them and stores the value in a variable called hourDiff.

Here is relevant part of the js.

To avoid a scope issue, a gobal variable called hourDiff is defined at top of the javascript outside any function"

```
var hourDiff = 0;

//Calulate the time difference and store the value in hourDiff
hourDiff = endDate - startDate;
```

The idea is to eventually appendd hourDiff to the gridview hyperlink control below and pass the name-value pairs as querystring to another page called Reseve.aspx

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="siteId" class="js_siteid" style="color:#111" runat="server" navigateurl='<%# String.Format("Reserve.aspx?id={0}&groupsize={1}&facilityFees={2}&extrahour={3}&depoitAmt={4}&cancelAmt={5}&keydeptAmt={6}", Eval("siteId"), Eval("capacity"),Eval("RentalFeeAmount"),Eval("ExtraHourAmount"),Eval("DepositAmount"),Eval("CancellationAmount"),Eval("KeyDepositAmount")) %>' Text='Select' />
```

Since the hyperlink is not exposed to the javascript until **after** search button is clicked, I have another javascript below that is used to apend hourdiff to the hyperlink and passed to another page.

This javascript is placed at the bottom of the html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var links = document.getElementsByClassName("js_siteid");
if ( links.length > 0 )
{
    links[0].onclick = function() {
        this.href += ( "&hoursdiff=" + hourDiff );
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>


  <script type="text/javascript">
                 **var hourDiff = 0;**
                $(window).load(function () {
                    $("#txtFromDate").datepicker();
                    $('#timeStart').timepicker({ showPeriod: true,
                        onHourShow: OnHourShowCallback,
                        onMinuteShow: OnMinuteShowCallback
                    });

                    $("#txtToDate").datepicker();
                    $('#timeEnd').timepicker({ showPeriod: true,
                        onHourShow: OnHourShowCallback,
                        onMinuteShow: OnMinuteShowCallback
                    });
                    function OnHourShowCallback(hour) {
                        if ((hour > 20) || (hour < 6)) {
                            return false; // not valid
                        }
                        return true; // valid
                    }
                    function OnMinuteShowCallback(hour, minute) {
                        if ((hour == 20) && (minute >= 30)) { return false; } // not valid
                        if ((hour == 6) && (minute < 30)) { return false; }   // not valid
                        return true;  // valid
                    }
                    $('#btnSearch').on('click', function () {
                        var sDate = $("#txtFromDate").val();
                        var sTime = $("#timeStart").val();

                        var eDate = $("#txtToDate").val();
                        var eTime = $("#timeEnd").val();

                        var startDate = new Date(sDate + " " + sTime).getHours();
                        var endDate = new Date(eDate + " " + eTime).getHours();

                        //Calulate the time difference
                         **hourDiff = endDate - startDate;**
                        //alert(hourDiff);

                        //Check if hour difference is less than 4 hours and show the message accordingly
                        if (hourDiff < 4) {
                            var r = false; $($("<div>A mininum of 4 hours is required!</div>")).dialog({ closeOnEscape: false, resizable: false, modal: true, open: function (event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); }, buttons: { Close: function () { r = false; $(this).dialog("close"); } }, close: function () { return r; } });
                            return false;
                        }

                        //Add the check condition if the user is above the 4 hours time frame
                        if (hourDiff > 4) {
                            var r = confirm("There may be additional fees for going over the 4 hours!");
                            if (r == true) { // pressed OK
                                return true;
                            } else { // pressed Cancel
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
        </script>
```

Each time I compile my code and clic the Select link, hourDiff always displays the value of 0 rather than the difference between start date and end date.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
Protected Sub ValidateDuration(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As ServerValidateEventArgs)
  Dim validator As Control = DirectCast(sender, Control)
  Dim row As Control = validator.NamingContainer

  Dim startHour As Integer = Integer.Parse(DirectCast(row.FindControl("startHour"), DropDownList).SelectedValue)
  Dim startMinutes As Integer = Integer.Parse(DirectCast(row.FindControl("startMinutes"), DropDownList).SelectedValue)
  Dim startAmPm As String = DirectCast(row.FindControl("startAmPm"), DropDownList).SelectedValue

  Select Case startAmPm
    Case "AM"
        If startHour = 12 Then
            startHour = 0
        End If

    Case "PM"
        If startHour <> 12 Then
            startHour += 12
        End If

    Case Else
        args.IsValid = True
        Return
  End Select

  Dim endHour As Integer = Integer.Parse(DirectCast(row.FindControl("endHour"), DropDownList).SelectedValue)
  Dim endMinutes As Integer = Integer.Parse(DirectCast(row.FindControl("endMinutes"), DropDownList).SelectedValue)
  Dim endAmPm As String = DirectCast(row.FindControl("endAmPm"), DropDownList).SelectedValue

  Select Case endAmPm
    Case "AM"
        If endHour = 12 Then
            endHour = 0
        End If

    Case "PM"
        If endHour <> 12 Then
            endHour += 12
        End If

    Case Else
        args.IsValid = True
        Return
  End Select

  Dim hoursDiff As Integer = endHour - startHour
  If endMinutes < startMinutes Then
    hoursDiff -= 1
  End If

  args.IsValid = hoursDiff >= 2
```

End Sub

Comment: Other than the statement `var links = document.getElementsByClassName("js_siteid");`, there's no evidence in the question of any elements with className `"js_siteid"`.

Comment: where do startDate and endDate get assigned?

Comment: @fnostro, please see entire javascript above.

Comment: Does `btnSearch` cause a postback? is it an asp:Button control or simple html button where `type=button`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 2015-02-27 ~13:40 EDT: Appending hiddenfield to hyperlink serverside**

I'm using GridView1 as I do not know the name of your gridview.
In the `GridView1` `RowDatabound` Event (note the addition of "&hourDiff={7}" to the end of the format string and the addiition of the hiddenfield value in the parameter list):

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
  If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
    dim hl as HyperLink = if(e.Row.FindControl("siteId"), Nothing)
    If hl IsNot Nothing then
      hl.NavigateURL = String.Format("Reserve.aspx?id={0}&groupsize={1}" & _
          "&facilityFees={2}&extrahour={3}&depoitAmt={4}&cancelAmt={5}" & _
          "&keydeptAmt={6}&hourDiff={7}",
          DataBinder.Eval("siteId"),
          DataBinder.Eval("capacity"),
          DataBinder.Eval("RentalFeeAmount"),
          DataBinder.Eval("ExtraHourAmount"),
          DataBinder.Eval("DepositAmount"),
          DataBinder.Eval("CancellationAmount"),
          DataBinder.Eval("KeyDepositAmount"),
          hf1.Value )
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

---

**Problem 1:** Each time I compile my code and click the Select link

the Select link in a Gridview is going to cause a postback and therefore `hourDiff` is going to be 0 everytime since a postback is going to force all js to be re-evaluated

**Problem 2:** 
Be aware that every control that causes a postback is going to reset your page javascript.  One way to get around that is to save to and restore from hidden field controls (`<asp:HiddenField ID="hf1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"...>`). then you can access like this: `$('#hf1').val(3.14);` and the value is preserved between postbacks.

Cookies or local storage are other options

Also, is there any reason that the calculation must occur clientside?  because you have another problem once you redirect to a new page.  Be aware that redirecting, even to the same page, is not a postback.

**Update 2015-02-26 14:30 EDT**
I cannot see your search code so I'm going to make an assumption that no matter how the user picks a start/end date/time there is a Search button that causes a postback with four fields (assuming `asp:TextBox`'s) of Search data, I'll call them: StartDate, StartTime, EndDate, EndTime.

The Search Button is going to cause a postback which should make the search fields available for use in the code behind.

Build 2 DateTime variables (S, E) and use the DataDiff() function to determine the difference you need.

In your case it would be something like this:

```
' At class level define the variable:
Dim hourDiff as DateTime = nothing

' In the gridview databinding event do your calculation
Private Sub GridView1_DataBinding(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles GridView1.DataBinding
  Dim S as New DateTime( <replace with relevant parameters> )
  Dim E as New DateTime( <replace with relevant parameters> )

  hourDiff = DataDiff(DateInterval.Hour, S, E)
End Sub

' Then in the row databound event append the difference to the hyperlink
Private Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
  If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
    dim hl as HyperLink = if(e.Row.FindControl("siteId"), Nothing)
    If hl IsNot Nothing then
      hl.NavigateURL = <build your Hyperlink and Append hourDiff>
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

---

**Amended 2015-02-26 18:06EDT**

> i would have preferred the option of using hiddenField if you could
>   explain how to tie hf1 to hourdiff.

Add a hidden field to your page like this:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hf1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
```

to js add this:

```
// define hourDiff
var hourDiff; 

// Using jquery place an object reference to the hidden field into hourDiff
hourDiff = $("#hf1");  

// Do your time calculations and assign results to hourDiff
hourDiff.val( time_calc_results );  

// The above places the results in the hidden field Value property
// which will be available in the code behind as as `hf1.Value` after postback
```

> I am spending more time trying to fix errors on the code you just posted.

Well that's to be expected as it's mostly from memory and is partially pseudo code.

> With regards to your latest code, does that mean that I try the javascript 
>   I posted at the top or use both?

The intent was that the search criteria could be selected Clientside or Serverside, the choice is yours.  But you have to be careful of problem 1. you need a way to preserve the calculation between posts.  Hence my suggestion for the Hidden Field.

**Worst case Scenario: 5+ postbacks**
In the worst case scenario you post back every time a user selects a time and date so at minimum you have 5 postbacks, one for each start and end date and time and then clicking search.  Posting back like this makes it pointless to do the calculations client side.  I hope you understand why.  Ideally, in this situation the user has made all the selections prior to selecting Search and then you calculation once server side.

**Scenarios 2: 1 Postback**
In this scenario you have js or jQ code picker that allow the user to select times and dates WITHOUT posting back to the server.  This is a great way to collect data.

1. If Clientside, you need to make sure the calculation is complete and stored in the Hidden Field before you post back
2. If Serverside you need to grab the four field and do the calculation in the Search button click event or in the Gridview DataBinding event.

In either case you need to modify the Hyperlink href.  This ***could*** be done client side...maybe.  It depends, if you cause a postback before getting a chance to update the `href` of the select link.

To me it looks like you added your own hyperlink to each row.  If that is so then you should be able to modify all the hyperlinks with a bit jquery code after you calc hourDiff

```
// Assuming hourDiff is defined as 
var hourDiff = $('#hf1');

... (other stuff)

// and you calc and assign to hourDiff as this:
hourDiff.val( endDate - startDate);

... (maybe more other stuff)

// then you modify your hyperlinks like this
$( "#GridView1 a.js_siteid" ).each( function( i, e ) {
    this.href += "&diff=" + hourDiff.val();
} );
```

> Also, I don't understand: 
>   `Dim E as New DateTime( <replace with relevant parameters> )`

It's the VB equivalent of what you are doing in the js code with the Date objects.  There are over a dozen ways to instantiate one so I just left it up to you to pick one that works for you.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand this. I mean the relationship between hf1 and hourDiff.

How are they linked?

Also, I would love to do it server side but I got stuck trying to do it server side. See updated server side code I attempted.

Comment: `asp:HiddenField` controls are rendered as hidden input fields (`<input type=hidden>`) and as such are part of the form and when the page is submitted its value is posted back with the form.  When you set the asp control property `ClientIDMode="Static"` then it prevents the compiler from mangling the id so it's very easy to find via javascript and jquery.   So a hidden field is a nice way to send client side calculated data to server side for processing and vice versa as input fields retain their value between postbacks.

Comment: I understand that much about asp.net hidden field.

What I am asking your help on is how does hf1 relate to hourDiff?

In other words, according to your post, I add hf1 as hidden control.

Then you said to access it using #hf1.val(3.14). Where do I put that #hf1 at the script with btnSearch or the script with the links? and what does the 3.14 represent, something like `#hf1.val(hourdiff)??
Thanks very much for your help

Comment: ok - based on the new code you posted it appears that the user has to select **Search** first which passes the start/end time information back to the server.  If that is true then it's a simple matter to calculate the difference and append it to each Select hyperlink: I'll ammend my above post with my thoughts

Comment: i would have preferred the option of using hiddenField if you could explain how to tie hf1 to hourdiff.

I am spending more time trying to fix errors on the code you just posted.

With regards to your latest code, does that mean that I try the javascript I posted at the top or use both?

Also, I don't understand:

`Dim E as New DateTime( <replace with relevant parameters> )`

Thanks very much for your help

Comment: I'll amend my post with explanations you asked for above.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help and patience.

Yes, you are correct, we are getting the startdate, enddate, starttime and endtime from jquery. jquery datepicker for date and jquery timepicker for dates.

You are also correct that when that hyperlink is only available after the search button (btnSearch) is clicked.

I will test the different scenarios and hopefully one of them works.

This issue has bogged me down now for days.

Thanks so much. I will be back to update you, hopefully, with good news that it is working with your great efforts.

Comment: At this point, I think I will leave you alone. You have given alot of your time and efforts. It is just not working.

I have added the `var hourDiff = $('#hf1');`. This replaced the one I had before.

Then this `hourDiff.val( endDate - startDate);` although it doesn't really make much sense to me.

Finaly, I suppose I was supposed to use this `$( "#GridView1 a.js_siteid" ).each( function( i, e ) {
    this.href += "&diff=" + hourDiff.val();
} );` in place of the links js.

Now, I get undefined assigned to hourdiff. There is some serious disconnect here.

Comment: You're welcome to whatever help I was able to offer. Just a few last things to help clarify your last comment. This:`var hourDiff = $('#hf1');` places a jquery object in hourDiff that is a reference to the hidden field. This:`hourDiff.val( endDate - startDate);` uses the val() property of the jquery object to assign the results of the calculation to the value attribute of the hidden field. If ever an object shows nothing it's usually due it's placement in the code or the result of a postback wiping out expected values. Typically you want to ensure the page is loaded first. see jquery ready()

Comment: @fnstro,

You are very kind person. Thank you so much for your help and patience.

It is just a bit frustrating. Each effort results to more frustration.

Today, for instance, I switched back to using service side.

If you look at the vb sub I posted earlier, I can't figure out how to append hourDiff to hyperlink.

I am not sure how good you are with asp.net - specically server side.

Since I have the hyperlink already on markup, how do I append hourDiff to it?

Even better, how do I move entire hyperlink to code behind?

Right now, what I have is causing an error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71897/discussion-between-fnostro-and-chidi-okeh).

Comment: Sorry I can't get into the chat. It says, `CHAT` undefined. Problably some js error. However, you are already my hero.

I got the value show now. In the vb I posted, I stored the value of hourDiff into hf1, just below, hourDiff=endhour-starthour.

If you have any solution to the other issue I raised, please share with me.

If you don't I will close this. I am very grateful. The issue is that I am getting undefined when using the ValidateDuration sub customValidator.

Comment: yes - i updated the post with a serverside solution to updating the hyperlink it's at the top of the post

Comment: Thanks so mcuh for all your help.